Does a finite-index subgroup of a Fuchsian group have the same set of cusps?
Suppose $G$ is a cofinite Fuchsian group, meaning that $\mathbb{H}/G$ has finite area. Let's also suppose it has a nonempty set of cusps $\mathcal{C}_G$, where we define a cusp to be a $c\in \mathbb{R}\cup \{ \infty \}$ such that there is a parabolic $g\in G$ with $g(c)=c$. If $H\leq G$ is a finite index subgroup, is it true that $\mathcal{C}_H=\mathcal{C}_G$?
I believe the answer is yes.
Here is my thinking: I know that a fundamental domain of $H$ consists of a finite number of translates of a fundamental domain for $G$, and that the ideal vertices of fundamental domains correspond to cusps. If $c$ is a cusp of $G$, then it is an ideal vertex of such a fundamental domain, and appropriately gluing adjacent domains of $G$ together should reveal that $c$ is a cusp of $H$ as well. I am having trouble phrasing this argument in group-theoretic terms. Could someone help me with it (or point out to me where my intuition is wrong, if my claim is false)?

Hint: This is just an algebraic fact; prove that if $H<G$ is a finite index subgroup then for every $g\in G$ there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $g^n\in H$.
